# PHP remove variable string length

Tags: php, str-replace

I get a string from a database. The string can look like this....

Homeland - Some Loose Ends Will Be Tied Up in Homeland's Finale

Game of Thrones - Star Jack Gleeson to Quit Acting After Series

I want to remove the title including the - in each string. I looked into str_replace() but i can only change some characters or remove the first x or last x characters. But that is different in any rule.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'll point you towards `preg_replace()`.

Comment: What guarantee do you have that the name of the show won't include hyphens?

Comment: That's a risk i'll take for now. The website has to be up and running first and this will go in the to do list. We enter the titles our selves so whe just have to keep this in mind for now.

Comment: What??? Jack Gleeson is going to quit!!!! Thats a bad news though :-p

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$title = explode('-', $title, 2);
$title = trim($title[1]);
```

First you split the title in the two parts, than you keep only the last one removing all extra whitespaces.

If you have at least **PHP 5.4**, you could do

```
$title = trim(explode('-', $title, 2)[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$title= explode(" - ", $string)[1];
```

Comment: Many people are still running versions of PHP that don't allow subscripting function calls.

Comment: would this be a safer way to do it?
    $title = explode(" - ", $string);
    $title = $title[1];

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for this (in particular, you can use `preg_replace`):

```
$episode = preg_replace('/.*?\s+-\s+/', '', $episode);
```

Regex autopsy:

- `.*?` a lazy match. Match as little as possible up until the rest of the matches are matched
- `\s+` a white space character matched 1 or more times
- `-` a literal `-` character
- `\s+` a white space character matched 1 or more times

Comment: Why do you need the capture group?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
$str='Homeland - Some Loose Ends Will Be Tied Up in Homeland\'s Finale';
$str = preg_replace('/(^[^-]*- ?)+/', '', $str);
echo( $str );
```

### Explanation

`$str` contains your complete string, and what the `preg_replace` do is replace the match string using the passed REGEX `/(^[^-]*- ?)+/` and replaced by and empty string `''`

the REGEX `/(^[^-]*- ?)+/` means:

> Anything the character the string starts with, how ever many time its repeated until the dash '**-**' replace all that by the empty the string